# interact with command line program

Tags: python, real-time, popen, pexpect

I want to comminicate with commandline program and get the output in real-time. I tried pexpect, Popen. But all failed.

I have a C program like this.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int x;
printf("hello");
scanf("%d",  &x);
printf("x=%d",x);
}
```

I compiled the program with gcc, the output is file 'a.out'.

'a.out' can be run like a bash shell.

When I run 'a.out' in terminal, I will get a 'hello', and then wait for my input.

I want 'a.out' to interact with python, and pexpect.
Problem:

1. Use Pexpect

   As I want to match anything, I use `pexpect(".*")` or `pexpect(r".*")` , but the before and after shows nothing(b''), while pexpect('hello') works fine.

   ```
   import pexpect
   x = pexpect.spawn('./a.out')
   x.expect('.*')
   print(x.before, x.after)
   x.expect(r'.*')
   print(x.before, x.after)
   x.expect('hello')
   print(x.before, x.after)
   ```
2. Use Popen

   ```
   import subprocess
   x = subprocess.Popen('./a.out', shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   ```

The t.poll() is always None, and the t.read() or t.readline() will make the program hangs.

Note, it has string "hello", but no new line.

Any line based method will not succeed.

Comment: This is the first time I ask questions in stackoverflow, sorry for the poor layout

Comment: I can't see the link between your C program and your python program. Would you mind explain it, pls? PS: The edit you did are still unclear to understand your question. Ask a friend if he can understand your question.

Comment: How are any readers suppose to know that, as it is not in your question? Would you mind put it, pls?

Comment: reading you, @frenk-liu, it seems that `a.out` can be run like it was a bash program, am I correct? PS: make sure that your python code is respectful of [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: @Andy K, Yes, you are correct.

Comment: where is the pexpect('hello')?

Comment: @Andy K, I reedit the code.

Comment: I'm not sure but close to sure that this `x.expect('.*')` will not look for anything, rather it will look for `.*`. My opinion would be to look for a way to do this `.*` instead of using this `'.*'` as for the latter you are formatting it as a chain of character.

Comment: pexpect always returns/sends raw bytes, that's why you get the `b,'any_string'`. Also .* doesn't return anything, so x.before and x.after won't return anything. https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#beware-of-and-at-the-end-of-patterns

Comment: I checked this. first I use x.expect('.'),  and I got b'h', then I use x.expect('.*'), x.after == b'ello' . But  at the very beginning, if I use  x.expect('.*') , I got nothing. Is it a bug of pexpect??  @Tejas Sarade

Comment: No, its not bug. What you are getting is x.after of previously matched x.expect.

Comment: @Andy K,  Yes, the x.expect('.*') is wrong, correct is x.expect('.+')

Answer (score 3):

You might want to make your C program easier to deal with readline() methods of expect by adding \n after all printf() outputs

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int x;
printf("hello\n");
scanf("%d",  &x);
printf("x=%d\n",x);
}
```

Then you can write Python program like this.

```
import pexpect
x = pexpect.spawn('./a.out')
print(x.readline())     # reads 'hello'
x.sendline('6')         # sends 6 with \n
print(x.readline())     # reads 6
print(x.readline())     # reads x=6
```

Output

```
b'hello\r\n'
b'6\r\n'
b'x=6\r\n'
```

Output can be converted from bytes to string using str() or decode() functions

For your purpose, using cmd module would be more hepful. Here is just sample example of how it works.

```
import cmd, os

class MyCli(cmd.Cmd):
    intro = "Welcome to my shell"
    prompt = '>'

    def emptyline(self):           # Do nothing for empty line
        pass

    def do_mycmd(self, user_cmd):  # When user enters mycmd execute a.out
        os.system("./a.out")

    def default(self, user_cmd):   # When user gives input that is not command print message
        print("Unknown command")

    def do_exit(self, user_cmd):   # Exit command
        print("goodbye")
        return True

ins1 = MyCli()
ins1.cmdloop()
```

Output

```
Welcome to my shell
>
>mycmd
hello
25
x=25
>
>exit
goodbye
```

Comment: No, infact, I am writing a python script and hope it can dealing with any command line programs.  @Tejas Sarade

Comment: Do you mean that, when you run Python script, in this case it should wait for user input and send it to command line program and get the output. Exactly like the original command line program when it run directly.

Comment: yes , exactly. I am developing online compiler. I hope the program can run interactively like local shell.

Comment: For that purpose cmd module is more useful. I have added sample program in the answer.

Comment: One important part of this answer: when you launch the C program from the Python script, its output is not a tty, and so `printf()` will buffer up all of its output until a newline is written.  That is, it's not necessarily a problem with the wiring on the Python side, the subprocess is probably not actually writing anything to its stdout, and adding the newlines in the printf calls will fix it.